# No options and cannot select. How to call data from database in Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, database, xmlhttprequest

I have a table form that contain elements like the code below:

```
<table border="1" bordercolor="#7695CC" id="table2">
<tr>
    <td class="tablesubtitle" align="center">No</td>
    <td class="tablesubtitle" align="center">Name Component</td>
    <td class="tablesubtitle" align="center">Name child Component</td>
    <td class="tablesubtitle" align="center"Point</td>
    <td class="tablesubtitle" align="center">Action</td>
</tr>                   
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><select name="component" onChange="NameComponent(this);">
        <option value="#">&nbsp;</option>
        <?php
            opendb();
            $query = "SELECT * FROM componentone";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $ID = $data['ID'];
                $name = $data['Component'];
                echo "<option value='$ID'>$name</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</td>
<td><div id='childcomponent'><select>
        <option value="#"></option>
        </select>
                                            </div>
    </td>
    <td align="center"><a href="result_point.php?menu_id=<?=$menu_id?>">0</a></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="button" value=" + " onClick="addRowToTable();"> | <input type="button" value=" - " onClick="removeRowFromTable();"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If you see an onChange function there, the function is for calling the results of data from the database to display the results in (see the div element) `<div id='childcomponent'>` after choosing one of options in the component name `<select name="component">`. These two elements are connected.

```
function NameComponent(combobox)
    {
        var code = combobox.value;
        if (!code) return;
        xmlhttp.open('get', '../template/get_component_name-opr.php?code='+code, true);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200))
            {
                 document.getElementById("childcomponent").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
            return false;
        }
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
```

Example: No. 1, component name I choose is AAA, this AAA have three childcomponent, are AAA1 AAA2 AAA3. After I chose AAA, the three of childcomponent (AAA1,AAA2,and AAA3) wwill display automatically.
This is the code when I call the results data to display to `<div id='childcomponent'>`:

```
<?php
include ("config.php");
include ("dbfunctions.php");

echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\" src=\"js/form_validation.js\"></script>";

echo "<select name='child_component'>";
echo "<option value=\"\">&nbsp;</option>";
opendb();
$query = "SELECT * FROM childcomponent WHERE ID='$_GET[code]' ";
$result = querydb($query);
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<option value='".$data['ID']."'>".$data['childcomponent_name']."</option>";
    }
echo "</select>";
?>
```

In the action, I wanted to add rows and remove rows.
This is the code by using Javascript to add rows:

```
<script language="Javascript">
function addRowToTable()
{
  var tbl = document.getElementById('table2');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  var iteration = lastRow;
  var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

  // left cell
  var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration);
  cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);

  // right cell
  var cellRightSel1 = row.insertCell(1);
  var sel = document.createElement('select');
  sel.name = 'component' + iteration;
  cellRightSel1.appendChild(sel);

  // select cell
  var cellRightSel2 = row.insertCell(2);
  var sel = document.createElement('select');
  sel.id = 'childcomponent' + iteration;
  sel.options[0] = new Option('','');
  sel.options[1] = new Option('', '');
  cellRightSel2.appendChild(sel);

  var cellRight = row.insertCell(3);
  var el = document.createElement('input');

  cellRight.appendChild(el);

}
<script>
```

My problem here is when I add row, the number two there is no options at all that I can select in the component name.
The question is, how to call data from database in javascript?
Calling the database from here, maybe?

```
var cellRightSel2 = row.insertCell(2);
  var sel = document.createElement('select');
  sel.id = 'childcomponent' + iteration;
  **sel.options[0] = new Option('','');
  sel.options[1] = new Option('', '');**
  cellRightSel2.appendChild(sel);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JS does not "call the database". JS has absolutely NO database functions built into it. JS **can** call a script on the server via AJAX which would talk to the database on JS's behalf. But that's like claiming you made a BigMac because you ordered one at the McD's counter. Beyond that... nice SQL injection holes.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not using jQuery here? Your code could be way simpler if you used it.

Comment: Are you trying to get data from a database when you do `addRow`? In that case you will have to write another Ajax call (similar to the one you have done for the `onChange`) and use the data in the response to build the table rows,

Comment: Honestly: are you looking for someone to code the solution for you, or do you really want to understand the problem? Sorry, but the description you put on your profile doesn't inspire much confidence.

Comment: @bfavaretto "are you looking for someone to code the solution for you, or do you really want to understand the problem?" = Both. I am looking for the confidence, but where I could find it? *hopeless*
Hummm.. I've not tried using JQuery, yet. Does it simpler and can call from a databse?

Comment: @MarcB Ohhhhhke, got that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of options:

1. Use the same idea you have for `NameComponent`: when the user clicks the Add Row button you make an Ajax call to the server and have PHP respond with the HTML you want to display in the new row. Then insert the HTML with innerHTML.
2. Change the Add Row button into a submit button. Then have PHP generate the updated page with the extra row.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, since you state you wish to understand the problem, I took some time to analyze your code in more detail. First of all, to answer your question, there is no way to "call the database" from javascript. What you can do is launch an ajax request to the server and use the response, like you did in your `NameComponent` function, like @WayneBaylor suggests.

Now, your code has many other problems. Here are the ones that I believe to be the most serious:

1. When you create a new row programatically with `addRowToTable`, it should be the same as default row you create with PHP. Your code creates a similar, but different row, which lacks the "change" event on the first component, and the div to contain the child component (it's directly inside the `<td>`). `addRowToTable` also breaks your HTML table by adding rows with 4 columns instead of the expected 5 (and the inuput on the 4th cell does nothing and has no label).
2. `addRowToTable` also has a problematic numbering logic (they way you set `iteration` to `tbl.rows.length`). Imagine you start with one row, and add three more. Then you delete the second row, and add one more to the end. Both the third and fourth rows will then be numbered "4", and worse: you'll have two elements with id `childcomponent4`, which is invalid.
3. Your "change" handler `NameComponent` will have to be reworked. You can't do `document.getElementById("childcomponent")`, because then you'd be always setting the contents to the div in the first row, instead of the row where the changed `<select>` belongs. You'll be looking for a childcomponent container div in that same row (which your current code does not create).
4. As @MarcB pointed out, you have a SQL injection hole on your PHP code. You shouldn't do `SELECT * FROM childcomponent WHERE ID='$_GET[code]'` before you are sure the  `$_GET[code]` contains a number. Otherwise, your database will be very vulnerable to attacks. By the way, if it's really a number, and your ID column on the DB is an int, you also don't need the single quotes between `$_GET['code']` (but note you do need single quotes around `code` in `$_GET['code']`, which you currently don't have).

I suggested you learn and use jQuery because it would really makes things simpler for you. For example, on `addRowToTable` it would be very easy to just clone a sample row from the table, instead of creating a new row from zero, using the plain js DOM manipulation methods. You probably realized they're a pain to use...

I hope this helps you put your code on the right track.